# runSignal works in the browser but not on the node console

Tags: frp, purescript

I have been playing with purescript and signals. I have a block of code

```
runSignal $ (every 2000.0) ~> logShow
```

which when compiled into a JS file(pulp browserify) as

```
main = do 
         runSignal $ (every 2000.0) ~> logShow
```

and executed on the browser, works as expected(logs something every 2 seconds), but gets stuck on the psci console. Why is this behaviour? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PSCi has two modes:

- It can use Node for execution of compiled JS (the default mode). In this mode, it starts a new Node process for each expression, and prints the result synchronously in the console.
- It can use a web browser for execution (using the `--port` option) via a websocket. In this mode, it sends a snippet of JS to a long-running browser process.

In the first mode, `runSignal` isn't going to do anything interesting, since it will start a timer and return immediately, but you can probably get something working easily using the second mode.

Comment: Thanks Phil. But the next psci prompt isn't even shown on running this line. It get's stuck and I have to do a ^C to interrupt it. Is this the result of synchronous running of the node process which keeps waiting for the result of this expression?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar behavior with neverending processes in psci.  A simple example would be...

```
module NeverEnding where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (log)
import Control.Monad.Rec.Class (forever)

main = forever $ do
  log "log"
```

If you load this module in psci and run `main`, you won't see any output.  From a workflow perspective, if you want to test something like this from the console, I suggest running `pulp --watch run --main NeverEnding`.  `--main` will set the module that you want as the main entrypoint. `--watch` will watch for file changes, and on change, kill the neverending process, recompile, and restart.